# accessing other classes from an interface class

Tags: uml, object-oriented-analysis

I am currently designing a software where the nurse eg nurse1 can create objects (for example Object1, object2) and assign attributes to the patient1, patient2 etc like blood pressure, measuring device used, the date of the measurement etc. through the Interface class shown in my design. How can for example patient1 view his blood pressure only without tampering with other attributes in any class?[image]

Comment: This is no interface at all and your design is just broken. What are those "objects" the `Nurse` can create? Is it some kind of patient log?

Comment: Yes. It is a patient log. The nurse logs information concerning the blood pressure of the patient, selects the Measuring device, enters the patients name etc. I believe the nurse does this when an object of the interface class is created. But the patient may view this log without tampering with the information. May be I should have called the Interface, InterfaceClass

Comment: I'll try to give you an answer in an hour or so...

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I will be anxiously waiting

Comment: Can you elaborate why you called your class interface? Is it an actual interface as defined in UML enabling to perform operations in blood measurements log? Or is it an application user interface so the thing a user (either a patient or a nurse) is actually facing?

Comment: Also are all measurements taken by a nurse or can the patient measure himself (e.g. at home) and only enter results?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your question is a bit too broad and there's no single answer to it. Anyhow, here's a design suggestion:

[image]

The `Nurse` realizes a `Logger` interfaces which's sole purpose is to add records to a patient log. Note that this could be extended to some kind of modification functions for a doctor or the nurse itself for the latest records, or the log can contain the id of the nurse so she can edit her own records only, or, or, or.

The `Logger` interface offers functions to create, (read, update, delete)  a patient log. It is fed with the patient id and the type of record. Again note that here's just a string for each record. In reality you want integer values/ranges for most of them, to make analyses and text only for a few of them.

The `Patient` has read only access to the log. This constraint need to be explained in the use case. Alternatively you could design a `CentralPatientLog` which explicitly controls access to the patient log files.

There a endless different ways to design this. So take this as basis for further discussions. Also note that the above design sketch contains errors (which I will not correct).

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I will try to go through, understand what you have just written and drawn and make adjustments. A million thanks